# Globalize, Heroku: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

I just added globalization (with the [globalize gem](https://github.com/globalize/globalize)) to a model.

*Model:*

```
class Information::Blog::Post < ApplicationRecord

    self.table_name = 'information_blog_posts'

    translates :title, :subtitle

end
```

*Migration:*

```
class CreateInformationBlogPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :information_blog_posts do |t|

            t.references :author, index: true


            t.datetime :published_at
            t.timestamps

        end
    end

    def up
        Information::Blog::Post.create_translation_table! title: { type: :string, null: false }, subtitle: { type: :string, null: false }
    end

    def down
        Information::Blog::Post.drop_translation_table!
    end
end
```

Now, in my seed I added this line:

```
post = Information::Blog::Post.create(id: 1, author_id: 1, title: 'Test', subtitle: 'Test test test test', locale: 'en')
```

And it seeded my local MySQL database perfectly fine. After deploying to heroku though, **resetting & migrating** my postres production database, I got the following error seeding the database:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "information_blog_post_translations" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"information_blog_post_tr...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"information_blog_post_translations"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:85:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:84:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:83:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:775:in `column_definitions'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:166:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:67:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:73:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:451:in `load_schema!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:233:in `load_schema!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:50:in `load_schema!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:446:in `load_schema'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:339:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/table_metadata.rb:39:in `has_column?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:91:in `block in create_binds_for_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:89:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:89:in `create_binds_for_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:34:in `create_binds'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause_factory.rb:21:in `build'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:612:in `where!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:605:in `where'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:69:in `last_chain_scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:126:in `add_constraints'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:28:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:5:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:97:in `association_scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:284:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:279:in `skip_statement_cache?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:302:in `find_target'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:269:in `load_target'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:41:in `load_target'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:1028:in `records'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:39:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:114:in `detect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:114:in `translation_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:72:in `fetch_attribute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:25:in `block in fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:24:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:24:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter_dirty.rb:34:in `store_old_value'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter_dirty.rb:8:in `write'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:31:in `write_attribute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb:96:in `block in define_translated_attr_writer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `public_send'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `_assign_attribute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:28:in `perform_attribute_assignment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:36:in `assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:23:in `block in assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize.rb:27:in `with_locale'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:203:in `with_given_locale'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/core.rb:337:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
/app/db/seeds.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:270:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "information_blog_post_translations" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"information_blog_post_tr...
                                          ^
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:85:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:84:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:83:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:775:in `column_definitions'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:166:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:67:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:73:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:451:in `load_schema!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:233:in `load_schema!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:50:in `load_schema!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:446:in `load_schema'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:339:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/table_metadata.rb:39:in `has_column?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:91:in `block in create_binds_for_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:89:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:89:in `create_binds_for_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:34:in `create_binds'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause_factory.rb:21:in `build'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:612:in `where!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:605:in `where'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:69:in `last_chain_scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:126:in `add_constraints'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:28:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:5:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:97:in `association_scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:86:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:284:in `scope'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:279:in `skip_statement_cache?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:302:in `find_target'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:269:in `load_target'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:41:in `load_target'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:1028:in `records'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:39:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:114:in `detect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:114:in `translation_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:72:in `fetch_attribute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:25:in `block in fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:24:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:24:in `fetch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter_dirty.rb:34:in `store_old_value'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter_dirty.rb:8:in `write'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:31:in `write_attribute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb:96:in `block in define_translated_attr_writer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `public_send'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in `_assign_attribute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in `block in _assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in `_assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `_assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:28:in `perform_attribute_assignment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/attr_encrypted-3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:36:in `assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:23:in `block in assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize.rb:27:in `with_locale'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:203:in `with_given_locale'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/globalize-6f9d3f38d132/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/core.rb:337:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
/app/db/seeds.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:270:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0.rc2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

Why is this just working locally with MySQL?

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @Pavan Yes, I did.

Comment: did you change one of your old migrations by chance? Only the latest migration gets run, the other ones don't get re-run

Comment: @maxpleaner Nah, I completely reset the database. So every migration has been run. This is the only migration I changed.

Comment: I think the migration only runs `change` or `up`, not both. Try to put your `up`/`down` into a `reversible do |dir|` block inside of `change` instead. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible  Also try to install Postgres locally and see if it also fails locally.

Comment: @Chloe Weird. Using reversible blocks I get the very same error in MySQL locally: `Mysql2::Error: Table 'slooob_development.information_blog_posts' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `information_blog_posts``

Comment: Maybe the Postgres driver does the migrations in a different order than the MySQL driver and `up` has different precedence over `change`. It sounds like it might be a bug with the gem and you'll have to file an issue with the gem maintainer on their Github project page. Sounds like `create_translation_table!` isn't running correctly. Oh, and that's not the same error or same table: `information_blog_post_translations`.

Comment: @Chloe Thanks for your help! I finally got around this problem by creating the translations table by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating the translations table by myself.

```
class CreateInformationBlogPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :information_blog_posts do |t|

            t.references :author, index: true


            t.datetime :published_at
            t.timestamps


            create_table :information_blog_post_translations, force: true do |t|
                t.references :information_blog_post, index: { name: 'idx_blog_post_translation_blog_post' }
                t.string :locale

                # Attributes

                ## General
                t.string :title, null: false
                t.string :subtitle, null: false
            end

        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to source code [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L788) Rails totally ignores `up`/`down` methods if there is a `change` one